# CSS broken with inline-block in safari - width of zero not set

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, safari

I am trying to create a horizontal accordion in twitter bootstrap (2.3.2). I have found some css online that works very well and allows me to utilize the existing js. This all works great - except in safari (iOS and Windows). In safari the collapsed element still retains some width  even though the width is correctly set to 0px.

I have created a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/3erSh/

The css I am using is:

```
.accordion-group, .accordion-heading, .accordion-body
{
    display:inline-block;
}
.collapse
{
    height:auto;
    width:auto
}
.collapse.height
{
    height:0;
    -webkit-transition:height .35s ease;
    -moz-transition:height .35s ease;
    -o-transition:height .35s ease;
    transition:height .35s ease;
}
.collapse.width
{
    width:0;
    -webkit-transition:width .35s ease;
    -moz-transition:width .35s ease;
    -o-transition:width .35s ease;
    transition:width .35s ease;
}
.collapse.width.in
{
    width:auto
}
.collapse.height.in
{
    height:auto
}
```

I am developing on windows and can replicate the problem using the safari downloaded from here:
http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1531

The problem seems to be with the inline-block elements. Can this be fixed with a little sprinkle of css magic?

Comment: Safari 5.1? Seriously? You should be testing 6.1 and 7 first.

Comment: Try set font-size/line-height to 0 to hide elements

Comment: Issue is in Chrome(Win 7) also.

Comment: Yes I should be testing in safari 6+ but I dont have a mac. The problem is seen on iOS devices. Its these that I care about most. If I can fix it on the safari i can download for windows I assume it will fix it on the iOS devices I really care about.

Comment: @Anon - setting font-size/line-height to 0 does not work. Thanks all the same.

Comment: FYI it seems its not the inline-block statment that is causing this issue. I can replace that with float:left; and stil see the problem :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help Anon.

As it happens it was easier to create this from scratch as suggested by Anon.

http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/N2GSV/23/

```
.accord-group, .accord-heading, .accord-body
{
    display:inline-block;
}
.accord-body 
{
    vertical-align:top;
    visibility:hidden;
    /* non zero width - for safari */
    margin-left:-1px;
    width:1px;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition:all 0.35s ease;
    transition:all 0.35s ease;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.accord-body.in 
{
    visibility:visible;
    margin-left:0px;
    width:100px;
}
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/N2GSV/23/) for html and js.

Answer (score 2):

Try use `max-width:0;` and `max-width:1000px;`. It's work for me

```
.collapse.width
{
    width:0px;
    max-width:0;
    -webkit-transition:width .35s ease;
    -moz-transition:width .35s ease;
    -o-transition:width .35s ease;
    transition:width .35s ease;
}
.collapse.width.in
{
    width:auto;
    max-width:1000px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/N2GSV/)

Comment: That works pretty good. I am seeing a weird 'bounce' on the transition to open though. Do you see that?

Comment: Yes, i see this too. Plz, replace 'width' in  transition with 'all'.  transition:all .35s ease;

Comment: I still get a bounce. Is bootstrap using jquery to manually animate? I see a style="width:auto;" on the div when viewing in the inspector. Maybe this is interfering?

Comment: Setting the max-width transition to very short and the final max-width to something closer to the actual final width seems to wrk pretty good. The first transistion is very abrupt - but seems 'ok'.http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/3erSh/9/

Comment: Setting the initial width to 1px seems to fix the first transition. When its collapsed after that there is an added element style="width:0px;" that messes it up. :-((    http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/3erSh/11/

Comment: My best effort so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/foetalstalk/3erSh/17/ - remove 'style' after element is hidden and always have a positive (non-zero) width.

Comment: Too many scripts for one elements. Recommend to write your own function and not to use this functionality.

Comment: I was coming to the same conclusion. Cheers Anon - you have been very helpful.